# Linking content types

Tags: nodes

I need to link content from one content type to another automatically so that when one of the type is updated with new content, the other gets filled automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to connect two different content types content. Add a field Entity Reference in one content type and reference it to another content type.

To auto update another content type content, you need to use [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7) on first content type, and get referenced nid and update second content type content using [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7).